# Get different combinations of words

Tags: r, text

I have a string `ch` and I want to get a specific output `out`. Please see below examples.

```
ch <- "A B"
out <- "A B AB"

ch <- "A B C"
out <- "A B C AB BC AC ABC"

ch <- "A B C D"
out <- "A B C D AB BC CD AC AD BD ABC ABD ACD BCD ABCD"
```

Basically I want to get all possible **going forward combinations** of all words present in a string as explained above.

How do I achieve this in the easiest way in R?

EDIT:

I tried following. But it seems to be giving all possible combinations in which case it will get difficult to filter out the cases I need.

```
e <- c("A", "B", "C")
> r <- expand.grid(e, e, e)
> r
   Var1 Var2 Var3
1     A    A    A
2     B    A    A
3     C    A    A
4     A    B    A
5     B    B    A
6     C    B    A
7     A    C    A
8     B    C    A
9     C    C    A
10    A    A    B
11    B    A    B
12    C    A    B
13    A    B    B
14    B    B    B
15    C    B    B
16    A    C    B
17    B    C    B
18    C    C    B
19    A    A    C
20    B    A    C
21    C    A    C
22    A    B    C
23    B    B    C
24    C    B    C
25    A    C    C
26    B    C    C
27    C    C    C
```

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to `split` the string by space (`strsplit(str1, ' '))`, loop by the sequence of length of 'v1', get the `combn` of 'v1' for sequence, `paste` the elements in output columns (`apply(..., 2, ...)`), `unlist` and `paste` again.  We can create a function ('f1') that does these and use it for multiple strings.

```
f1 <- function(str1){
  v1 <- strsplit(str1, ' ')[[1]]
  paste(unlist(sapply(seq(length(v1)), function(i)
        apply(combn(v1, i), 2, paste, collapse=""))), collapse= ' ')
  }

ch <- "A B"
f1(ch)
#[1] "A B AB"

ch <- "A B C"    
f1(ch)
#[1] "A B C AB AC BC ABC"

ch <- "A B C D"
f1(ch)
#[1] "A B C D AB AC AD BC BD CD ABC ABD ACD BCD ABCD"
```